# how to work with maven under eclipse ("This compilation unit is not on the build path of a java project")

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have installed the m2 plugin for eclipse, but  i no longer can create packages, i have to create folders. This way one cannot create a java class directly, but have to create a text file with .java extension. All the nice things, like eclipse writing down the package name of the class and the imports, are gone!

Besides, whenever i try to autocomplete method names or code, all i get is a nasty warning: "This compilation unit is not on the build path of a java project". So all the ide functionalities are gone! eclipse becomes just a variation of notepad.

thanks

Comment: Why is it you think you can't create a Class? Are you sure the project has been properly set up for use with Maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i restarted my machine the issue got solved.